# Generic arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I Have four `EF` classes with a similar structure and a Generic Class that holds `EF` structure and some other props and methods, and want to write a generic method cast generic to the desired `EF`.

```
private List<T> CastGenericToEF<T>(List<GenericClass> GenericList)
{
    List<T> Target = new List<T>();
    foreach (GenericClass I in GenericList)
    {
        //How can I do to create an Instance of T?
        ..... 
        // Some proccess here 
    }
    return Target;
}
```

My question: How can I do to create a new instance of **T type** or get the type of **T**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define that T can have new()

```
private List<T> CastGenericToEF<T>(List<GenericClass> GenericList) where T: new()
{
    List<T> Target = new List<T>();
    foreach (var generic in GenericList)
    {
        //How can I do to create an Instance of T?
        var tInstance = new T();
        // Some proccess here 
        var typeOf = typeof(T);

    }
    return Target;
}
```

To access properties/methods of T you'll have to specify it's type in some way. Without a specification, T can be just anything...

the following example defines an Interface somewhere and then specifies that T must actually implement that interface. If you do so

```
    interface IGenericClass
    {
        void SomeMethod();
    }
```

you can access properties or methods defined by the interface

```
    private List<T> CastGenericToEF<T>(List<GenericClass> GenericList) where T : IGenericClass, new()
    {
        List<T> Target = new List<T>();
        foreach (var generic in GenericList)
        {
            //How can I do to create an Instance of T?
            var tInstance = new T();
            tInstance.SomeMethod();
            // Some proccess here 
            var typeOf = typeof(T);

        }
        return Target;
    }
```

Comment: Tks a lot. for now can't accept your answer, must wait 10 minutes.

Comment: Just another little question, how can i do to get Access to properties of ``T``

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez see update, put please, if you have more questions, just ask a new one

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a constraint on T:

```
private List<T> CastGenericToEF<T>(List<GenericClass> GenericList) where T : new()
```

You can then create an instance of T with `new T()`

To get the type of T, just use `typeof(T)`